# "cannot open source file "vcruntime_string.h" (dependency of "string.h")" in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn C programming. And I am using VS Code for running almost everything.
But none of my C Codes execute. The c_cpp_properties.json is configured with the MinGW header files library path included in the "msvc-x64" section. It says "cannot open source file "vcruntime_string.h" (dependency of "string.h")" all the time.

Comment: Not sure what the question is?

Comment: Have you been able to make a HelloWorld from a tutorial work in your environment?

Comment: Please see the documentation on building a [mcve] -- *specific* code and a *specific* error message would make this much more answerable.

Comment: VS Code is just the IDE - what compiler did you intend to use? MinGW indicates gcc, but msvc-x64 is the Microsoft compiler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's weird that it is not letting you compile by not finding string.h dependency. I suggest to try the following:

1. Try compiling your files either with gcc or g++ (depending on the language you're using) directly from the terminal, to see if you get the "a.out" file.

Ex: Open your terminal. Find your .c files (if you're programming in C) `gcc *.c` then `./a.out`

2. Try using CodeBlocks, Build and Run to see if you get the same error.

**If 1 or 2 worked, it means your VS software didn't like something when you made the installation process. Reinstall VS.**

Comment: It could be that the OP's code doesn't compile at all, for reasons unrelated to the development environment -- this answer assumes that their code is correct, which is (until they edit more details in the question) presently an unfounded presumption.

Comment: Correct. Assuming that he is programming the right way

Comment: *Nod*. While the downvote isn't mine, I would probably hold off on answering a question until it has enough details to have some certainty that an answer is correct. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem."

Comment: Cool. Just trying to help giving an option he could use

Comment: *nod*. Rereading the question, I actually like this answer more now than I did at first -- the question *does* have some details, albeit buried in the text rather than exposed, and they support your diagnosis; I've tried to edit the question to move the details towards the title, which should make the question's center (and thus the answer's strength) more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it just by reloading the window.
You can either press Ctrl + R or type "Developer: Reload Window" in the command palette.
You can open the command palette either by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P or going to "View"(up left corner) then "Command Palette..."